# Ordinary Wine: Any Lenient Positions?

Tags: halacha, stam-yenam

Are there any halakhic opinions that allow drinking ordinary wine not produced by Jews?

Comment: Apparently Rav Abadi briefly was lenient over a decade ago, till he discovered that it is indeed actually handled by people and not just machines (?)

Comment: @Loewian That's just a question of Hashgacha. Everyone would agree that wine not touched by non-Jews is fine (according to halacha). The OP is asking stronger than that, IIUC.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know enough to even know if that's my question. I would be interested in any information about positions that exist, whether about actual status of wine or about need for hashgahah.